# SQL stored procedure to add dynamic rows group by page to material column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I need the `Page` row dynamically after each group of `Material` row. Some of `Material`s are grouped with a name in the `Page` column.

SQL query:

```
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = '
        WITH RowData AS (
            SELECT 
                Page, 
                Material, 
                SalesOffice, 
                ROUND(' + (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @SHOW = 'QT' THEN
                            CASE
                                WHEN @MATGROUPUNIT = 'EA' THEN
                                    'SUM(ISNULL(Qty, 0) + ISNULL(CredQty, 0))'
                                WHEN @MATGROUPUNIT = 'CV' THEN
                                    'SUM((ISNULL(Qty, 0) + ISNULL(CredQty, 0)) / ISNULL(UnitCase, 1))'
                                WHEN @MATGROUPUNIT != 'EA' AND @MATGROUPUNIT != 'CV' THEN
                                    'SUM((ISNULL(Qty, 0) + ISNULL(CredQty, 0)) * ISNULL(MatUnit, 1) / 1000000)'
                                ELSE
                                    'SUM((ISNULL(Qty, 0) + ISNULL(CredQty, 0)) * ISNULL(MatUnit, 1) / 1000000)'
                            END
                        ELSE
                            'SUM(ISNULL(SaleValue, 0) + ISNULL(CreditValue, 0)) / 100000'
                    END) + ',2) Quantity
            FROM 
                table
            WHERE 
                PERIOD = @PERIOD AND OFFICEGROUP = @OFFICEGROUP AND Yr = @YEAR AND Division = @DIV AND MatGroupUnit = @MATGROUPUNIT ';

        IF @LineType = 1 
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND SalesOffice + MatGroupCode NOT IN (SELECT Location + MatGroup FROM Line2)';
        ELSE IF @LineType = 2
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND SalesOffice + MatGroupCode  IN (SELECT Location + MatGroup FROM Line2)';

        IF @PC IS NOT NULL
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND PC = @PC ';

        IF @QTR IS NOT NULL
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Qtr = @QTR ';

        SET @SQL = @SQL +   'GROUP BY  Page, Material, SalesOffice
            ), RowSums AS (
                SELECT Page, Material, SUM(Quantity) AS Total
                FROM RowData
                GROUP BY Page, Material WITH ROLLUP
            )
            SELECT 
                ISNULL(RS.Page, ''Total'') AS Page,
                ISNULL(RS.Material, ''Total'') AS Material, 
                ' + @PivotColumns + ', 
                RS.Total
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    Page, Material, SalesOffice, Quantity
                FROM RowData     
            ) AS P
            PIVOT (
                SUM(Quantity)
                FOR SalesOffice IN (' + @PivotColumns + ') 
            ) AS PivotData
            INNER JOIN RowSums RS ON PivotData.Material = RS.Material;';

        --PRINT @SQL; 
END
```

I want the row after each group of `Material` like attached image.

That group name is `Page` column value and total. `FB` is the name for above columns, so total value is `FB-TOTAL`. Like that, `SUM` is also required.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: The rest of your script would be helpful as well, because there are some efficiencies you can make. Please don't post images of code or data, only text.